# Howto Setup TDengine Cluster with Helm

Tags: kubernetes, time-series, kubernetes-helm

For coders who want to install TDengine cluster in kubenetes.

[TDengine](https://github.com/taosdata/TDengine) is an open-sourced time-series database under GNU AGPL v3.0, designed and optimized for the Internet of Things (IoT), Connected Cars, Industrial IoT, and IT Infrastructure and Application Monitoring. Besides the 10x faster time-series database, it provides caching, stream computing, message queuing and other functionalities to reduce the complexity and cost of development and operation.

This Q&A is for anyone want to use it in kubenetes.

Answer (score 0):

### Install Helm

```sh
curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh \
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3
chmod +x get_helm.sh
./get_helm.sh
```

Helm will use kubectl and the kubeconfig setted in chapter 1.

### Install TDengine Chart

Download TDengine chart.

```sh
wget https://github.com/taosdata/TDengine-Operator/raw/main/helm/tdengine-0.1.0.tgz
```

First, check your sotrage class name:

```sh
helm get storageclass
```

In minikube, the default storageclass name is `standard`.

And then deploy TDengine in one line:

```sh
helm install tdengine tdengine-0.1.0.tgz \
  --set storage.className=<your storage class name>
```

If you are using minikube, you may want a smaller storage size for TDengine:

```sh
helm install tdengine tdengine-0.1.0.tgz \
  --set storage.className=standard \
  --set storage.dataSize=2Gi \
  --set storage.logSize=10Mi
```

If success, it will show an minimal usage of TDengine.

```sh
export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace default \
  -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=tdengine,app.kubernetes.io/instance=tdengine" \
  -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
kubectl --namespace default exec $POD_NAME -- taos -s "show dnodes; show mnodes"
kubectl --namespace default exec -it $POD_NAME -- taos
```

You can try it by yourself:

[image: post script]

For a small sql test:

```sh
kubectl --namespace default exec $POD_NAME -- \
  taos -s "create database test;
    use test;
    create table t1 (ts timestamp, n int);
    insert into t1 values(now, 1)(now + 1s, 2);
    select * from t1;"
```

### Values

TDengine support `values.yaml` append.

To see a full list of values, use `helm show values`:

```sh
helm show values tdengine-0.1.0.tgz
```

You cound save it to `values.yaml`, and do some changs on it, like replica count, storage class name, and so on. Then type:

```sh
helm install tdengine tdengine-0.1.0.tgz -f values.yaml
```

Some usefull values:

```yaml
taoscfg:
  # Starts as cluster or not, must be 0 or 1.
  #   0: all pods will start as a seperate TDengine server
  #   1: pods will start as TDengine server cluster. [default]
  CLUSTER: "1"

  # number of days per DB file
  #TAOS_DAYS: "10"

  # number of days to keep DB file, default is 10 years.
  TAOS_KEEP: "3650"
```

### Scale Up

You could see the details in chapter 4.

First, we should get the statefulset name in your deploy:

```sh
export STS_NAME=$(kubectl get statefulset \
  -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=tdengine" \
  -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
```

Scale up is very simple, the next line scale up the TDengine dnodes to 3, no other commands required.

```sh
kubectl scale --replicas 3 statefulset/$STS_NAME
```

Re-call `show dnodes` `show mnodes` to check:

[image: scale up]

### Scale Down

> NOTE: scale-down is not completely work as expected, use it with caution.

Also, scale down requires some extra step:

Get the dnode endpoint and drop it iteratively:

```sh
kubectl --namespace default exec $POD_NAME -- \
  cat /var/lib/taos/dnode/dnodeEps.json \
  | jq '.dnodeInfos[1:] |map(.dnodeFqdn + ":" + (.dnodePort|tostring)) | .[]' -r
kubectl --namespace default exec $POD_NAME -- taos -s "show dnodes"
kubectl --namespace default exec $POD_NAME -- taos -s 'drop dnode "<you dnode in list>"'
```

Drop one dnode may cause several seconds or minutes.

[image: drop dnode]

### Uninstall

```sh
helm uninstall tdengine
```

Helm doest not automatically drop pvc by now, you can drop it manually.